# Death Screen not Loading

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have been testing pygame with a couple of friends, and we've run into a problem where a desthscreen that is supposed to load when the player steps on spikes just isn't loading. 
The if statement is definitely triggering, and the command to create the death screen works if it isn't in the if statement. We have no idea what the problem is.

If you want the textures download them here:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B57S6Qow33ZrYS02Rk5ZQnVzNFk&usp=sharing

Here is the code:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#cloud position
cloudx = -600
cloudy = 0
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()


#Dimensions
TILESIZE=40
SCREENWIDTH=15
SCREENHEIGHT=12

#Display Surface
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH*TILESIZE,SCREENHEIGHT*TILESIZE))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

#Player-controlled Character
PLAYER = pygame.image.load("Character1.png").convert_alpha()
PlayerPos = [8,6]
SPEED = 0.1
CanMove = True
pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 30)

#Materials
O = 0
RFLOOR1 = 1
RWUP1 = 2
RWDOWN1 = 3
RWLEFT1 = 4
RWRIGHT1 = 5
RWUPLEFT1 = 6
RWUPRIGHT1 = 7
RWDOWNLEFT1 = 8
RWDOWNRIGHT1 = 9
RFLOORDOOR1 = 10
RWUPDOOR1 = 11
RWDOWNDOOR1 = 12
RWLEFTDOOR1 = 13
RWRIGHTDOOR1 = 14
CLOUD = 15
SONIC = 16
DEATHSCREEN = 17
SPIKES = 18

#Textures
textures = {O : pygame.image.load("Black.png"),
            RFLOOR1 : pygame.image.load("RockFloor1.png"),
            RWUP1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallUp1.png"),
            RWDOWN1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallDown1.png"),
            RWLEFT1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallLeft1.png"),
            RWRIGHT1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallRight1.png"),
            RWUPLEFT1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallUpLeft1.png"),
            RWUPRIGHT1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallUpRight1.png"),
            RWDOWNLEFT1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallDownLeft1.png"),
            RWDOWNRIGHT1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallDownRight1.png"),
            RFLOORDOOR1 : pygame.image.load("RockFloorDoor1.png"),
            RWUPDOOR1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallUpDoor1.png"),
            RWDOWNDOOR1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallDownDoor1.png"),
            RWLEFTDOOR1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallLeftDoor1.png"),
            RWRIGHTDOOR1 : pygame.image.load("RockWallRightDoor1.png"),
            CLOUD : pygame.image.load("cloud.png"),
            SONIC : pygame.image.load("sonic.png"),
            DEATHSCREEN : pygame.image.load("DeathScreen.png"),
            SPIKES : pygame.image.load("Spikes.png")
            }

#Room1
room1Tilemap = [[O,  O,  O,           O,       O,       O,       O,       O,         O,       O,       O,       O,       O,            O,  O],
                [0,  O,  O,           O,       O,       O,       O,       O,         O,       O,       O,       O,       O,            O,  O],
                [O,  O,  RWUPLEFT1,   RWUP1,   RWUP1,   RWUP1,   RWUP1,   RWUPDOOR1, RWUP1,   RWUP1,   RWUP1,   RWUP1,   RWUPRIGHT1,   O,  O],
                [O,  O,  RWLEFT1,     RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1,   RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RWRIGHT1,     O,  O],
                [O,  O,  RWLEFT1,     RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1,   RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RWRIGHT1,     O,  O],
                [O,  O,  RWLEFT1,     RFLOOR1, SPIKES,  RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1,   RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, SONIC,   RFLOOR1, RWRIGHT1,     O,  O],
                [O,  O,  RWLEFT1,     RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1,   RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RWRIGHT1,     O,  O],
                [O,  O,  RWLEFT1,     RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1,   RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RWRIGHT1,     O,  O],
                [O,  O,  RWLEFT1,     RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1,   RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RFLOOR1, RWRIGHT1,     O,  O],
                [O,  O,  RWDOWNLEFT1, RWDOWN1, RWDOWN1, RWDOWN1, RWDOWN1, RWDOWN1,   RWDOWN1, RWDOWN1, RWDOWN1, RWDOWN1, RWDOWNRIGHT1, O,  O],
                [O,  O,  O,           O,       O,       O,       O ,      O,         O,       O,       O,       O,       O,            O,  O],
                [O,  O,  O,           O,       O,       O,       O,       O,         O,       O,       O,       O,       O,            O,  O]]

room1UpBound = 2.5
room1DownBound = 8.5
room1LeftBound = 2.5
room1RightBound = 11.5

#Tilemap Settings
tilemap = room1Tilemap
UpBound = room1UpBound
DownBound = room1DownBound
LeftBound = room1LeftBound
RightBound = room1RightBound

#Main Loop
while True:
    if (PlayerPos[1] > 5 and PlayerPos[1] <6 and PlayerPos[0] > 9 and PlayerPos[0] <10):
        SPEED = 0.5
    if (PlayerPos[1] > 5 and PlayerPos[1] <6 and PlayerPos[0] > 4 and PlayerPos[0] <5):
        Screen.blit(textures[DEATHSCREEN],(0,0))

    print (PlayerPos)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if CanMove == True:
                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if keys[K_w] and PlayerPos[1] > UpBound:
                    PlayerPos[1] -= SPEED
                if keys[K_s] and PlayerPos[1] < DownBound:
                    PlayerPos[1] += SPEED
                if keys[K_a] and PlayerPos[0] > LeftBound:
                    PlayerPos[0] -= SPEED
                if keys[K_d] and PlayerPos[0] < RightBound:
                    PlayerPos[0] += SPEED


    for row in range(SCREENHEIGHT):
        for column in range(SCREENWIDTH):
            Screen.blit(textures[tilemap[row][column]], (column*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE))



    Screen.blit(PLAYER,(PlayerPos[0]*TILESIZE,PlayerPos[1]*TILESIZE))

    Screen.blit(textures[CLOUD].convert_alpha(),(cloudx,cloudy))

    cloudx+=1

    if cloudx > (0):

        cloudx = -600
        cloudy = 0

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(24)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply overdrawing your screen with the tiles.
Just move your Deathscreen blit somewhere at the end of your loop and it "works":

```
#...
Screen.blit(PLAYER,(PlayerPos[0]*TILESIZE,PlayerPos[1]*TILESIZE))

Screen.blit(textures[CLOUD].convert_alpha(),(cloudx,cloudy))

if (PlayerPos[1] > 5 and PlayerPos[1] <6 and PlayerPos[0] > 4 and PlayerPos[0] <5):
    Screen.blit(textures[DEATHSCREEN],(0,0))

cloudx += 1
#...
```